# Calls From External Web Components in PWAs

Tags: ajax, node-modules, web-component, progressive-web-apps, native-web-component

I have many web components (JS Modules of HTMLElements) that are located in different app servers. They all get combined (imported and used) in one master ui app that uses these web components together. The problem is, the Ajax calls from these external web components that are imported into master ui app will get called from the master ui app host and not the web component external URL/host.

Can I make it so that the imported web components uses their remote host and not the local host of the importee (Master UI App) when they do their own external Ajax calls?